# incoming number without country code not recognized

Tags: contacts, nokia-lumia-800, 7.8

My lumia 800 can't seem to match an incoming call number to a contact. The contacts have the country code but the incoming number does not. Incoming SMS have the country code and are matched to the proper contact.

Any ideas?

Comment: What network are you on?

Comment: Starhub, Singapore

Comment: Please try if this will fix the country code issue http://www.nokia.com/us-en/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA138384

Comment: It is now December 2014 and this issue still remains...and it appears nobody did anything since 2010, still back in WP 7. I posted a bug fix on the MS Feature suggestion page. Here is the link if anybody wants to add additional vote: https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6792382-bug-fix-callerid-for-international-numbers-for-in Let's try and get this sorted. It is really shameful that old phones never had an issue with this! T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happened to me too. I am not absolutely sure, but I believe it was just after I updated my Lumia 800 to WP7.8. I flashed it with Nokia Care Suite and the ROM was intended for the asia-pacific market, so it could be that.

Are you in the same situation?

Comment: hmm yes i did exactly that too and the ROM was not for my current region. I can't remember if this started happening right after though. I've been traveling and using different SIMs and I noticed this only once I got back.

Maybe I'll just wait for the proper ROM to be released (hopefully sometime this month) and try another flash to see if it fixes it.

Comment: I flashed my phone again with the firmware variant for my region, and everything appears to be working once again

Answer (score 0):

can you post a screenshot of the incoming call? I noticed that some of the country codes that use to come in as +49 or +44 (Germany and UK) are now coming in as 49 XYZ which will not match the contact. I wonder if that's the same issue you are seeing. Verizon only, ATT still seems to work just fine on the same device

Comment: there's no country code coming in anymore. e.g. the country code on the contact is +65xxx but the incoming call is just xxx without the +65. I wonder if this is done by the carrier and not the phone..

Comment: I am 99% sure that this is a carrier thing because the phone works with the information it gets from the carrier... If they don't pass you this information then there is no way the phone could know...

Comment: I don't know.. i'd guess the phone should be smart enough to figure out the local country code and get the full phone number. I think that's how most phones work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Windows Phone 8 problem across most brands and I've contacted Microsoft who said the work around is to have 1 contact e.g. joe blogs with 2 numbers (mobile number = +64 22 123456 and mobile number 2 = 022 123456) (+64 is my New Zealand country code) and saved in your contacts (I use Outlook sync via an Exchange server).

The contacts will then display properly on the incoming call.  I realise this is a pain as you have to double up on everything for now and I'm waiting for a fix to be released from Microsoft along with the rest of you.  There is a reg hack but that may be for the more technically minded.